# Error connecting: Error while fetching server API version: Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm very new at Ansible. I've run following ansible PlayBook and found those errors:

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: linx
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:

    - name: install docker-py
      pip: name=docker-py

    - name: Build Docker image from Dockerfile
      docker_image:
        name: web
        path: docker
        state: build

    - name: Running the container
      docker_container:
        image: web:latest
        path: docker
        state: running

    - name: Check if container is running
      shell: docker ps
```

Error message:

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error connecting: Error while
>   fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', error(2, 'No such
>   file or directory'))"}

And here is my folder structure:

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── docker
│   └── Dockerfile
├── hosts
├── main.retry
├── main.yml
```

I'm confused that `docker` folder is already inside my local but don't know why I encountered those error message.

Comment: I would guess "No such file or directory" is because the docker unix sock is not at `/var/run/docker.sock` where it traditionally lives. Have you tried increasing the log verbosity to get more details? `ansible-playbook -vvvv`

Comment: I've found error that `docker` service is not started yet after installed it.

Comment: @mdaniel @PPShein  how do I make sense of ` ERROR - Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(111, 'Connection refused'))` ; what is this Server api version that is being referrer to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found solution is `Docker` daemon is not working after `Docker` was installed by `Ansible`. It's required to add following command in my play board.

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: install docker
      yum: name=docker

    **- name: Ensure service is enabled
      command: service docker restart***

    - name: copying file to remote
      copy:
        src: ./docker
        dest: /home/ec2-user/docker
    - name: Build Docker image from Dockerfile
      docker_image:
        name: web
        path: /home/ec2-user/docker
        state: build
    - name: Running the container
      docker_container:
        image: web:latest
        name: web
    - name: Check if container is running
      shell: docker ps
```

Comment: You'll want to use `service: name=docker state=started` to keep the playbook from continually bouncing the docker daemon

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel appreciate it.

Comment: @PPShein how did you figure out that the daemon was not working?

Comment: @DJ_Stuffy_K it's required to start after it's being installed.

Comment: I had a similar problem but I hadn't add user account to the docker group.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem. I am trying to perform a `docker login` and get the same weird error. In my case, the ansible user does not have the necessary docker credentials. The solution, in that case, is to switch to a user with docker credentials:

```
- name: docker login
  hosts: my_server
  become: yes
  become_user: docker_user
  tasks:
    - docker_login:
        registry: myregistry.com
        username: myusername
        password: mysecret
```